# Why do I get varied result in js:list component?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using `jr:list` component in my jasper report. My report looks like below:

```
<background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="37" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="513" height="37" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="123c1330-2ed6-436c-90d7-49820b8d47b1"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["SUMMARY"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="256" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="2" width="514" height="20" uuid="eb5b00f3-c370-4c7f-bb10-b7589ff293ff"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="listDataset" uuid="f7dbd610-a453-4692-87b5-ace0329bbe11">
                        <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="20" width="514">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="2" width="328" height="18" uuid="d307fa41-0962-4b17-812d-774262e55e9e"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LABEL_VALUE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="328" y="2" width="185" height="18" uuid="fa972e53-dc8a-402e-96ad-9428b402ccd8"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ATTRIBUTE_VALUE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
    <noData>
        <band height="200">
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="513" height="37" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="123c1330-2ed6-436c-90d7-49820b8d47b1"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["SUMMARY"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="39" width="417" height="20" uuid="fb562548-2f38-4d3d-84a5-118b2cd354d3"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["No data to be displayed in this report"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </noData>
```

Here in the report my dataset query returns 20 rows, but the `jr:list` component displays only 11.

Are the remaining ones hidden or do I need to adjust my band height? 
Please I need help!

Comment: Hi, could you precise a little bit more what report your are talking about when you say `Here in the report` and `here in my report` please ? Feel free to edit your post to add precisions

Comment: Have you tried to use `Stretch with Overflow` option ?

Comment: maybe they went to page 2?

Comment: yes i tried with Stretch with Overflow

Comment: I was not kidding this has nothing to do with stretch with overflow, if you have (please double check and log query) 20 records, 20 records will be displayed. If you don't believe this is true include data in CVS and give us complete jrxml